# NSInteger to another View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to pass an `NSInteger` to my Other View Controller:

```
NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemView:sender];
```

This was implemented in a `UIButton`, Im thinking of using the `NSUserDefaults` like this sample code here:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:4 forKey:@"integer"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But I can't do it with my code above.
Is there other methods.

Comment: I know I just want to use the NSUserDefaults for this: `NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemView:sender];`

Comment: Create property of NSInteger variable in view Controller where u want to pass. Now provide your nsinteger to viewController's nsinteger by . instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSUserdefaults to pass value from one Viewcontroller to another. Use the below code:

```
NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemView:sender];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:index forKey:@"integer"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can retrieve it on another view by using the following code:

```
 NSInteger savedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"integer"];
```

Comment: How to retrieve it another view?

Comment: sorry `nsuserdefault` is not a way to pass and get data in between viewcontroller. use `@property` encapsulation

Answer (score 1):

From the view controller the UIButton is in, you need to get a reference of your other view controller, then have a property on it to set the value.

One way, would be to have a property on the UIViewController that holds the UIButton to assign a reference to the view controller you need to set a value on.  Set that value when you make the button view controller.

Another way, would be to have a reference to the target view controller in your application delegate, which you can get to from anywhere via the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] call.

You may also want to search StackOverflow more, this question I am sure has been answered before...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:4 forKey:@"integer"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: I mean how to pass this `NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemView:sender];`

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"integer"]; will help you to retrieve the value.

Comment: How to retrieve it another view?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use property to pass value to another view controller if, you are transiting from current view controller to that view controller and you need that value only in next view controller not in entire app.I mean suppose you are in viewController1 and you are transiting from viewController1 to viewController2.And you want index value in viewController2.In this case you can declare property in viewController2.h as:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)int indexInViewController2;

synthesize in viewController2.m as follows:

@synthesize indexInViewController2;
```

and while transiting from viewController1 to viewController2 you can pass value as follows:

```
viewcontroller2Obj.indexInViewController2 = [carousel indexOfItemView:sender];
```